# PostgreSQL - array value must start with "{" or dimension information

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, any

I’m trying to create a function which will filter based on ANY in a supplied text array.  The function is raising the following: “ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information” when attempting to execute a query within a pgplsql function.  The query works fine when the exact SQL statement is run in a query window.

The following illustrates the issue with a simplified sample.

Given the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE b
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    item_id character varying(2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT b_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And sample data:

```
id  item_id
1      A
2      B
3      D
4      T
5      G
6      T
7      B
```

And function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_item_ids() RETURNS integer[] AS
$BODY$DECLARE
    qry text;
    ids integer[];
    items text[];
BEGIN
    items := ARRAY['A','B','C']::text[];
    qry := format('SELECT id FROM b WHERE item_id = ANY(%L)', items);
    raise notice '%', qry;
    execute qry into ids;
    raise notice 'ids:%', ids;
    return ids;
END$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

When the function is run the following output is generated:

```
NOTICE:  SELECT id FROM b WHERE item_id = ANY('{A,B,C}')

ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_item_ids() line 9 at EXECUTE statement

********** Error **********
ERROR: array value must start with "{" or dimension information
SQL state: 22P02
Context: PL/pgSQL function get_item_ids() line 9 at EXECUTE statement
```

Copying and pasting the "SELECT id FROM b WHERE item_id = ANY('{A,B,C}')" statement into a Query windows yields the following expected results:

```
id integer
   1
   7
   2
```

I have tried many other options, including type casting, different quoting, and using the array_to_string and unnest functions.  Can anyone explain what's happening and suggest an alternative which would work?

Answer (score 4):

Try this statement inside your function:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT ARRAY(SELECT id FROM b WHERE item_id = ANY($1))' INTO ids USING items;
```

- Use [`USING`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to safely execute a dynamic statement. This method is preferable to inserting data values into the command string as text (with `format`).
- You need to wrap the returned rows with the `ARRAY` constructor to produce an `integer[]` (or refactor your function to return a `SETOF integer` if that's what
  you actually want).

Answer (score 0):

Given the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_item_ids(items text[]) RETURNS integer[] AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN ARRAY(SELECT id FROM b WHERE item_id = ANY (items));
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

The following query:

```
SELECT get_item_ids('{"A",  "B"}'::text[])
```

Shows this:

```
{1,2,7}
```

On the other hand,  the function:

```
CREATE TYPE id_record AS (id integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_item_ids2(text[]) RETURNS SETOF id_record AS
$BODY$
 SELECT id FROM b WHERE item_id = ANY ($1);
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL VOLATILE;
```

The query:

```
SELECT id FROM get_item_ids2('{"A",  "B"}'::text[])
```

Gives you:

```
+----+
| Id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  7 |
+----+
```